# Tree SHA is not a tree object [] - Error faced while creating a git commit using go-github package

Tags: go, github, github-api

I am trying to implement git-commit using git api and "github.com/google/go-github/github" package. I having issues creating a new commit (Tree SHA is not a tree object []). Following my code and

```golang
br, _, err := client.Repositories.GetBranch(context, "arnavbhutani09", "readmerequest", "7june")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        parent, _, err := client.Git.GetCommit(context, "arnavbhutani09", "readmerequest", *br.Commit.SHA)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        tree, _, err := client.Git.GetTree(context, "arnavbhutani09", "readmerequest", *br.Commit.SHA, false)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    
    sha2 := tree.GetSHA()
        tree2 := &github.Tree{SHA: &sha2}
        commit := &github.Commit{
            SHA:     &sha2,
            Message: github.String("First Commit Using APIs"),
            Tree:    tree2,
            Author: &github.CommitAuthor{
                Name:  github.String("Arnav Bhutani"),
                Email: github.String("arnavbhu@usc.edu"),
            },
        }
        newcommit, _, err := client.Git.CreateCommit(context, "arnavbhutani09", "readmerequest", commit)
```

Comment: Can you convert your code into runnable version?

Comment: Having the same issue, ever managed to sort this out?